# How to enable mod_info in Apache?

Tags: apache, apache2, apache2.2, apache-modules

I've gone through the Apache guide to enable to mod_info.

As per doc:

- To configure mod_info, add the following to your `httpd.conf` file.

  ```
  <Location /server-info>
      SetHandler server-info
  </Location>
  ```
- You may wish to use mod_access inside the `<Location>` directive to limit access to your server configuration information:

  ```
  <Location /server-info>
      SetHandler server-info
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from yourcompany.com
  </Location>
  ```
- Once configured, the server information is obtained by accessing

  ```
  http://your.host.dom/server-info
  ```

In my case this link is not giving any info. Is there anything I need to install as mod_info.c or something? Is there anything I need to put as AddModule or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There should be a mod_info.so that must be on a path Apache 2 can find. For example, I have:

```
kdp@darwin ccl $ locate mod_info.so
/usr/lib64/apache2/modules/mod_info.so
```

Then, I have these in my httpd.conf:

```
ServerRoot "/usr/lib64/apache2"
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
```

This is made available by a snippet in `/etc/apache2/modules.d/00_mod_info.conf`:

```
<IfDefine INFO>
# Allow remote server configuration reports, with the URL of
# http://servername/server-info
<Location /server-info>
    SetHandler server-info
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
</IfDefine>
```

(The `IfDefine` is only needed because of the way stuff is set up on Gentoo.)

Answer (score 2):

Check if info_module is loaded.

```
% /usr/local/sbin/httpd -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep info_module
```

If it is not loaded, add following line to httpd.conf. Note that `path/to` must be replaced with appropriate path.

```
LoadModule info_module path/to/mod_info.so
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.

1. When I check ./apachectl -l,  mod_info has not been installed.
2. To install the Mod_info or any module, First Compile and install Apache by ./configure --enable-info make make install

   More info for install module : http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/manual60/install.html
3. Check ./apachectl -l, mod_info would be there in the list
4. Enable server-info by updating httpd.conf
5. invoke url  http://your.host.dom/server-info

One thing I am not sure why apache mod_info not installed default installation.

Comment: "why apache mod_info not installed default" - mod_info is very much an "additional" module for development purposes only. It should be never be enabled in a production environment. So it should never be enabled in a "default installation". There are many other Apache modules that are not enabled by "default", as they are simply not required in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: Note that the `apachectl -l` lists modules compiled along Apache. However, Apache is capable of dynamically loading modules and thus does not require you to compile them in the server directly.